# Case Insensitive Array.Contains in Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, case-insensitive, stringcomparer

I'm trying to use Array.Contains on a string array within a Linq query:

```
var otherMatchingDevices = from d in selectedDevices
                           from c in mldb.Companies
                           where d.CompanyID == c.CompanyID && c.Deleted == 0
                           where searchTerms.Contains(d.Name.ToString(), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || searchTerms.Contains(c.CompanyName.ToString(), StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                           select d;
```

When the query is evaluated it crashes with "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'Contains'.

I tested this code using the StringComparer and it works fine and prints out "fOO":

```
string[] sList = { "fOO", "bar" };
string[] array = { "foo" };
List<string> stringlist = sList.ToList();
var qry = from s in stringlist
          where array.Contains(s, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
          select s;
if (qry.Count() > 0) Console.WriteLine(qry.First().ToString());
```

Can anyone show me how to use a case insensitive Array.Contains within a Linq query? I do NOT want to convert the original string ToUpper() or ToLower() as it is expensive and it changes the original data.

Comment: Are you using LINQ2SQL or LINQ2Entities? If so, then that's why it's not supported.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @MichaelDunlap Using a Linq to SQL Class.

Comment: `ToUpper` is probably not that expensive, why do you think so?

Comment: @Magnus Each time we call ToUpper() it creates a temporary string that is created and managed by GC, which takes more time and uses more memory. I also hate changing the original source data from the original state in the database, its confusing to me.

Comment: @IanK.CO You really should do some tests and see if it really is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

Your first snippet is invoked using **Linq to SQL**, this means that it will eventually be translated into SQL. So, whether comparison will be case-sensitive or not depends on the `COLLATION` of your table column. That's why Linq throws the exception, because it cannot guarantee case-sensitivity.

Your second query snippet is performed using **Linq to Objects**, hence string equality can be enforced, since the actual `string` is already in-memory.

Comment: Thanks, that illustrates why the Contains method can't be used on the Linq to SQL class, also the collation of the table didn't occur to me. Thanks @haim770

Answer (score 2):

> I tested this code using the StringComparer and it works fine and
>   prints out "fOO":

LINQ to Objects is different than LINQ to SQL/Entities. The latter needs to convert your query into a SQL expression, hence it doesn't understand what `StringComparsion` is.

You can use `AsEnumerable()` on your query to bring the data in-memory:

```
var otherMatchingDevices = (from d in selectedDevices
                            from c in mldb.Companies
                            where d.CompanyID == c.CompanyID && c.Deleted == 0)
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(searchTerms.Contains(d.Name.ToString(), 
                                               StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || 
                                   searchTerms.Contains(c.CompanyName.ToString(), 
                                               StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                            .ToArray()
```

Comment: If one is going to do the filtering in memory (big warning on that as it might be quite slow) I would suggest putting `searchTerms` into a non case sensative hashset.  `HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: The code here doesn't work but the answer is useful, I get the basic idea and I see the problem now. Thanks @Magnus